Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{nz}}{n!(z^2 + n^2)}$ defines a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$
I'm doing some review of complex analysis and have come across this question. Show that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{nz}}{n!(z^2 + n^2)}$$defines a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$.
I know I'd like to show that the series converges uniformly on compact sets, and thus is meromorphic. I'm a bit confused on how to actually do this: all of my attempts result in some exponent in the numerator, which makes this a bit tricky for me to think of a way to show uniform convergence.
Any hints would be very appreciated: thank you!

Hint: It suffices to show uniform convergence on a given square $[-N,N] \times [-N,N]$. On this square, use in $\sin nz = {\displaystyle \frac{e^{inz} - e^{-inz}}{2i}}$ that
$|e^{inz}|, |e^{inz}| \leq e^{Nn}$ and that for $n$ large enough one has ${\displaystyle \bigg|\frac{1}{z^2 + n^2}\bigg| \leq \frac{2}{n^2}}$ since ${\displaystyle |z^2| < \frac{n^2}{2}}$.

I see. Thanks! very helpful
